# Radio buttons are not displayed in the “payment & shipping information” section in the case of reorder by admin magento 2.4

Tags: css, magento2.4, admin-panel

```
- sales > orders > view > and Click Reorder and check "payment & shipping information” section
```

Radio btn Not Showning admin panel. Check below image

[image]

Comment: Any error on console or magento log files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add your `css` file. Below is the file path.

```
app/code/{themename}/OrderItem/view/adminhtml/web/css/

.page-wrapper .page-content .order-details .admin__field-option .admin__field-label{
    padding-left: 23px;
}
.page-wrapper .admin__control-radio:checked + label:after {
    left: 0;
}
#order-data .admin__control-radio + script + label:before {
    border-radius: 1.6rem;
    content: '';
    transition: border-color 0.1s linear, color 0.1s ease-in;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
    color: transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 1.6rem;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 1.6rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
#order-data .admin__control-radio + script + label {
    position:relative;
}
#order-data .admin__control-radio:checked +  script + label:after {
    background-color: #514943;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    height: 10px;
    left: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Now, Just `upgrade & deploy`. You can see Radio Btn will display to `“payment & shipping information”` Section

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the CSS looks for an input + label. You can apply this patch that puts the script tag before the input button.

How to apply patches: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching.html

**composer.json:**

```
"extra": {
    "patches": {
        "magento/module-sales": {
            "Fix to show radio buttons when creating orders": "patches/magento/module-sales/Adminhtml_Order_RadioButtons_Fix.patch"
         }
     }
}
```

**patches/magento/module-sales/Adminhtml_Order_RadioButtons_Fix.patch**

```
--- a/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/billing/method/form.phtml
+++ b/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/billing/method/form.phtml
@@ -21,6 +21,11 @@
         ?>
         <dt class="admin__field-option">
         <?php if ($_methodsCount > 1): ?>
+            <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderEventListenerAsTag(
+                'onclick',
+                "payment.switchMethod('" . $block->escapeJs($_code) . "')",
+                'input#p_method_' . $block->escapeJs($_code)
+            ) ?>
             <input id="p_method_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code); ?>"
                    value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code); ?>"
                    type="radio" name="payment[method]"
@@ -30,11 +35,6 @@
                     <?php endif; ?>
                    data-validate="{'validate-one-required-by-name':true}"
                    class="admin__control-radio"/>
-            <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderEventListenerAsTag(
-                'onclick',
-                "payment.switchMethod('" . $block->escapeJs($_code) . "')",
-                'input#p_method_' . $block->escapeJs($_code)
-            ) ?>
         <?php else:?>
             <span class="no-display">
                 <input id="p_method_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code); ?>"
```